# Vector field of a pipe

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

> Suppose that in a circular pipe of radius $r$, water is flowing in the direction of the pipe, with speed $r^2-a^2$, where $a$ is the distance to the axis of the pipe.  Write the vector field describing the flow if the axis of the pipe is the unit circle in the $(x, y)$ plane.

I know the value of a is $\sqrt{z^2+(x^2+y^2-1)^2}$.  However, I also need to find the direction so that with the direction and magnitude I can get the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to find the magnitude of the vector, but then I am stuck on the direction part.  My line of thought was that thw answer would be found multiplying the magnitude with the unit vector that would give me direction.  However, I do not know how to find the direction.  I tried to set it up in 2-d and then I suppose  I could use a vector projection by having the vector from the field project onto the vector of the point (ie, project the vector emanating from point (x, y) onto vector (x, y)).  However I do not know how to set up the equations.

Comment: If I let (x, y) be the vector from the origin then based on that the a = sqrt (x^2+y^2)-1 in the two d perspective,  but I don't know how to find the other magnitude and how to put this with 3d information I know.